# Is there a way to create a custom download link for a google drive file with my own domain

Tags: url-rewriting

Sorry for my poor knowledge about it. I would appreciate if anybody could explainme how can I create a custom download link for a google drive file. I got a domain in freenom.com and I want to change the download link of a google drive file to use my domain name in the url
What I’m try to do is avoid the final url docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/... using a custom link with my domain.
Is that possible?
I know it sound crazy but in my workplace they block docs.google url with a proxy filter and others cloud services like multcloud.com and koofr.eu too. Beside using proxy web or vpn is very suspect for they. 
So I need a way to download my files with my own url without lifting suspicions trace. 
I know is a nightmare but you never wish to live here. The only internet where I can download something is in my workplace. 
Any solution with google colab may helpme too. Maybe create a temporal server via python in google colab and asign my domain name. But I just don’t know how to do it. With flask-ngrok I create one in google colab but the link I obtain is through de domain ngrok and Is blocked too. 
The objetive is to create a custom download  link to one file that doesn’t lifting suspicions trace and maybe reemplace in the future the file in google drive rename it so that keep the same path. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks for your time

Comment: I am not sure but maybe this will help: https://techlabuzz.com/host-website-on-google-drive-with-custom-domain/

Comment: I use that article and create a static web but when y click download on the link that I had previously created in my static web it just redirect to the download link of google drive

Comment: Sorry, the link is the best I can offer. You will have to pioneer a solution. Don't forget to post an answer when you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

I did it, finally I did it. I’m a beginner, so for me, founding a method to circumvent the stupid proxy filters of my workplace without leaving any suspects in order to download files from the internet is great!!!!!! wonderful!!!!!!. Also I got to say that in my country the price of the internet is a madness. Imagine that you would have to pay the equivalent of 250 dollars of your salary for only 2 gigabytes of data usage in your cellular. And also imagine that you would have to pay the equivalent of 375 dollars of your salary monthly for only 30 hours per month through adsl modem connection with the ridiculous speed of 1 Mbit/s. But only in my workplace the internet is free and fast (at least for me). Add to that situation the fact that they are watching you every move you do in your internet traffic. 
As a communist country they control everything and in my workplace they have a man only for censure the internet blocking any suspicious page they found, and if they catching you using vpn or proxy web you receive a big problem. They block google drive, dropbox, and any other cloud storage services. Also they block any site you can use to download files if that site is not related to your work.

But hey, I finally found a way. First I got some free domains in freenom.com and I put them a name related with my work in order to not leave any suspicious trace in my web traffic. Then I got a free hosting service and associated each domains with a Wordpress site retouched in order to apparent something related with my work. Then I use my internet in my cellphone for download files from internet to my google drive account using google colab in order to store my files. After that I use google colab to upload my files from google drive to the ftp account of one of my Wordpress site created and then I create download links for all my file with my own domain name. And finally in my workplace I prepare a curl download script to download my files intermittently in order to not leave the appearance of downloading a big file traffic consuming. Finally I download the equivalent of 1 gb per day. Sad but true. I’m working now in a way to create a free ssl connection for my downloads with authentication system that won’t let the censor man to access to my links. Mabe with a Wordpress plugin